# Compiling error on OSX but not on Windows or Linux

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I have a C program that I was able to compile on windows using Code Block (which I believe uses GCC compiler) and on Linux using terminal gcc compiler. I tried to compile it on OSX using eclipse, code block for mac, terminal gcc, and even Qt but they all give me the same set of errors:

```
hw1.c:9:19: error: conflicting types for 'mergesort'
struct listnode * mergesort(struct listnode *data)
                  ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:6: note: previous declaration is here
int      mergesort(void *, size_t, size_t,
         ^
hw1.c:27:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 4, have 1
        ahead = mergesort(ahead);
                ~~~~~~~~~      ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:1: note: 'mergesort' declared here
int      mergesort(void *, size_t, size_t,
^
hw1.c:28:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 4, have 1
        bhead = mergesort(bhead);
                ~~~~~~~~~      ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:1: note: 'mergesort' declared here
int      mergesort(void *, size_t, size_t,
^
hw1.c:68:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 4, have 1
   node = mergesort(node);
          ~~~~~~~~~     ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:281:1: note: 'mergesort' declared here
int      mergesort(void *, size_t, size_t,
^
```

Comment: It seems there's already a `mergesort` function declared in the `<stdlib.h>` system header file, which is declared differently from your function. You might think about renaming your function?

Comment: Possibly, since it's not a standard C (or POSIX) function there might be some preprocessor macro to disable it. Read the header file.

Comment: Whoa, I changed the function's name and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely due to git.

*stdlib.h* on OS X already has a method called mergesort in it, so you cannot have that method declared in your code.

I suggest changing the name of `mergesort` to something else, like `myMergesort` (or something along that line).

Source:
[See here.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/195773)